# Is the order of the heading, content and footer of a section matter?

Tags: html

Is the order of the heading, content and footer of a section matter ?
for Example,

is this logical ordering :

```
<article>   
    <h1>This is the heading</h1>
    <content><p>This is the content ...</p></content>
    <footer><p>this is the footer</p></footer>
</article>
```

same for computers comparing to the next illogical ordering :

```
<article>   
    <content><p>This is the content ...</p></content>
    <footer><p>this is the footer</p></footer>
    <h1>This is the heading</h1>
</article>
```

Comment: The [content element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/content) is for use with shadow DOM, it does not signify the primary content of a section and you are using it incorrectly in your examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semantic markup and accessibility are both important when writing HTML, you have to keep in mind what makes sense to both machines and end users.

Sure, you "could" put elements in any order and style them so they appear to be in a completely different order, but what happens when someone views your website with a screen reader or something similar.

In addition to this the order of your elements is very important when SEO is concerned, the automated search bots that crawl your website don't care what the page "looks" like and have a very structured way in which they identify key areas such as navigation, main content areas, headings and links.

Positioning isn't black and white either, you could have multiple footer elements on one page which would be perfectly fine as long as you have a way to express which footer related to the parent page which is done using an ARIA role.

```
<body>
    <article>
        Something
        <footer>Something else</footer>
    </article>
    <footer role="contentinfo">
    </footer>
</body>
```

This will identify the footer with the role as a "navigational landmark", as footers primarily store navigation.

The same goes for a nav element, you could use it for any type of sub-navigation within your website multiple times in whatever order you'd like in addition to using it for your primary navigation as long as you used role="navigation" on the primary nav.

http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles

It's very easy to get carried away with using HTML5 elements but as long as you keep them structured semantically within their parent elements and give machines a way to identify key areas of your markup you will be A-OK.

```
<body>
    <header role="banner">
        <nav role="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <article role="main">
        <header>
            <h1>Article Heading</h1>
        </header>
        <aside>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Article 1a</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Article 1b</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Article 1c</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </aside>
        <p>Yip, dippidy doo.</p>
        <section role="complementary">
            <h2>Top Articles</h2>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Article 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Article 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Article 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </section>
        <footer>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">PrevArticle</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Next Article</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </footer>
    </article>
    <footer role="contentinfo">
        Copyright
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, yes. Element order is significant. (That is not necessarily the case with other SGML/XML derived markup languages).

This is trivial enough to test by looking at the output in a web browser (the standard tool for presenting HTML to the reader) and noticing that the rendered document doesn't make sense.